# Tabla de decisiones guiada (.gdst) ¿escrita en XML?

Tags: java, xml, drools

alguien que pudiera ayudarme con lo siguiente?

Tengo que analizar un código y dicho código implementa el uso de reglas de negocio, he investigado y se están usando tablas de decisiones guiadas, así que me he puesto a indagar en qué son y hay cientos de ejemplos en los cuales desarrollan algunas y las testean con códigos sencillos, pero no he ecnontrado nada similar a cómo están manejadas en el proyecto que analizo, y que al abrir el archivo me encuentro con una especie de código XML, algo así:

```
    <decision-table52>
  <tableName>RuleTable</tableName>
  <rowNumberCol>
    <hideColumn>false</hideColumn>
    <width>50</width>
  </rowNumberCol>
  <descriptionCol>
    <hideColumn>false</hideColumn>
    <width>150</width>
  </descriptionCol>
  <metadataCols/>
  <attributeCols>
    <attribute-column52>
      <typedDefaultValue>
        <valueString>FilterRules</valueString>
        <dataType>STRING</dataType>
        <isOtherwise>false</isOtherwise>
      </typedDefaultValue>
      <hideColumn>false</hideColumn>
      <width>100</width>
      <attribute>agenda-group</attribute>
      <reverseOrder>false</reverseOrder>
      <useRowNumber>false</useRowNumber>
    </attribute-column52>
  </attributeCols>
  <conditionPatterns>
    <Pattern52>
      <factType>Message</factType>
      <boundName>f1</boundName>
      <isNegated>false</isNegated>
      <conditions>
        <condition-column52>
          <typedDefaultValue>
            <valueString></valueString>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <isOtherwise>false</isOtherwise>
          </typedDefaultValue>
          <hideColumn>false</hideColumn>
          <width>100</width>
          <header>DOMAIN</header>
          <constraintValueType>1</constraintValueType>
          <factField>domain</factField>
          <fieldType>String</fieldType>
          <operator>==</operator>
          <parameters/>
        </condition-column52>
```

.... Y sigue y sigue...

Y en los ejemplos que he encontrado, la notación es como lo siguiente:

//row 12
rule "Basic_12"
salience 10
when
$order : Order( itemsCount > 0, itemsCount <= 3, deliverInDays == 1 )
then
insert( new Charge( 35 ) );
end

Entonces no sé porque lo que yo tengo es distinto, si es tipo de notación más vieja de Drools o no sé, el caso es que además de esto, se me complica leerlas, y he encontrado que en las condiciones, pareciera ser que no se compara con nada, si ves en el XML que puse, termina con una tag "==", entonces no me da la impresión de algo lógico dentro de una tabla de reglas. Intenté exportar y estructurar manualmente la data en Excel esperando leer más amigablemente la tabla, pero me encuentro con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entnces, no me queda claro si al final sí se está aplicando una regla para evaluación y si se está tomando una acción después de ello.

Si alguien conociera de este tipo de anotación y supiera cómo estos archivos son manejados y cómo se comportan en el RunTime, cómo son accesados, tuviese documentación o comentarios, acerca de ella, me serviría muchísimo conocer la estructura y el significado de todos esos Tags para poder hacer un análisis bien, y no quedarme sólo en conjeturas.

Como dato adicional, se están utilizando las herramientas de Drools y KieServer, y dichos archivos de tablas de decisiones (.gdst) están dentro de un .jar.

Gracias